# GridView Row checkboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I have a gridview in my .NET web app:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwQueues" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="gvwQueues_PageIndexChanging"
                    PageSize="5" Width="577px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="Item Number">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Directory" HeaderText="Directory">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Yes" runat="server" Text = "Yes" />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="No" runat="server" Text = "No"/>

                           <%-- <asp:CheckBoxList ID="IsActive" runat="server">
                               <asp:ListItem>Yes.</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>No.</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>--%>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>   
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to use the checkboxes:- "yes" or "no" to call appropriate functions on the server side that would make each item on the gridview row "Active" or "inactive".

Active means the item shows up for all users, Inactive means the item doesnt show up for any users, except for the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two modifications might me needed to make your logic work.

a. Try using Radiobutton in the place of using Check Boxes so that the user will be able to select **ONLY ONE OPTION** either 'Yes' or 'No'. Also note you need group these radio buttons like below to let only one of these radio buttons selectable. So replace your 'IsActive' template field with below:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="yesRadioButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="IsActiveGroup" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonIsActive_CheckedChanged" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="noRadioButton" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="IsActiveGroup" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonIsActive_CheckedChanged" />
       </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And assign both of its CheckChanged event to `RadioButtonIsActive_CheckedChanged` method.

b. Below is the code for the Code behind mehtod `RadioButtonIsActive_CheckedChanged`

```
 protected void RadioButtonIsActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvwQueues.Rows)
            {
                RadioButton yesRadioButton = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("yesRadioButton");
                if (yesRadioButton.Checked)
                {
                    //Make Items Active
                }

                else
                {
                    //Make Items Inactive
                }
            }
        }
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the check box to call a function when it changes?

Then all you need to do is add OnCheckedChanged

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Text = "Yes" 
OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged"/>
```

Serverside you write the function you want it to do

```
public void chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Make active inactive
}
```

Out side of this are you asking about roles, or binding to a grid?

Comment: How do I tell the server what is the value of the checkbox ?

Comment: chkStatus.Checked will give you true or false value depending upon check/uncheck

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DataKeyNames` for the grid view.

try this once.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwQueues" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="gvwQueues_PageIndexChanging"
                PageSize="5" Width="577px" DataKeyNames="ItemNumber">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text">
                        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="Item Number">
                        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Directory" HeaderText="Directory">
                        <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkYes" runat="server" Text="Yes"  OnCheckedChanged="YesOrNo_OnCheckedChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNo" runat="server" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="YesOrNo_OnCheckedChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />

                       <%-- <asp:CheckBoxList ID="IsActive" runat="server">
                           <asp:ListItem>Yes.</asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem>No.</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>--%>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>   
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And you can catch the Item Number using `ClientID` of sender argument

```
protected void YesOrNo_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkSender = (CheckBox)sender;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvwQueues.Rows)
    {
        if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkYes = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkYes");
            CheckBox chkNo = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkNo");
            if (chkSender.ClientID == chkYes.ClientID || chkSender.ClientID == chkNo.ClientID)
            {
                int ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(gvwQueues.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value);//here is the item number
                if (chkNo.Checked)
                {
                    chkYes.Checked = false;
                    //code to inactive
                }
                else if (chkYes.Checked)
                {
                    chkNo.Checked = false;
                    //code to activate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more suggestion is better to use `Radiobuttons` instead of `Checkboxes`.
You need to handle many conditions by using `Checkboxes` in your case.